# Is it possible to use smarty template without tpl file?

Tags: php, loops, templates, foreach, smarty

I need to assign data to javascript source.
Is it possible to use smarty template without tpl file.
Like this...

```
$sHtml = '
    {foreach from=$myArray key=k item=v}
       <li>{$k}: {$v}</li>
    {/foreach}
';

$arr = array(9 => 'Tennis', 3 => 'Swimming', 8 => 'Coding');
$oSmarty = new smarty();
$oSmarty->assign('myArray', $arr);
$result = $oSmarty->fetch($sHtml);

echo $result;
```

Return like this...

```
<li>9: Tennis</li>
<li>3: Swimming</li>
<li>8: Coding</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Smarty 3 on you can do that with

```
$smarty->fetch('string:'.$content);
```

See here fore more information: [String Template Resources](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl)

If you are using Smarty < 3 you could save the content of `$sHtml` in a temporary file and pass the file name to the fetch call:

```
$smarty->fetch('file:/full/path/to/tmp/file');
```

Comment: @WoojungSong not that I am aware of. But you can save the content of `$sHtml` in a temporarly file and pass the filename to the fetch call. See my updated answer.